# MYSQL LEFT JOINing the latest record from another table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a training_stats table (current due training) and I also have a completed_training table.

What I want to do is query due training with the last completed date from the completed table.

I've nearly got what I want, I get the due training, but they are duplicated with each completed record(as there are many completed records to each current due), and I only want single rows and the latest completed date.

I've been trying to use MAX, and when I run the MAX query independently, I get the last record. But when the MAX query is in the join, it is returning all completed rows.

This is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT s.course_stat_id
      ,o.org_name
      ,u.id
      ,u.first_name
      ,u.last_name
      ,a.area_id
      ,a.area_name
      ,tc.course_id
      ,tc.course_name
      ,s.assigned_on
      ,s.due
      ,s.pass_mark
      ,s.completed_on
      ,completed.complete_training_id
      ,completed.complete_date
FROM training_stats s
JOIN organisations o ON o.org_id = s.org_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT complete_training_id
          ,user_id
          ,area_id
          ,course_id
          ,max(completed_on) AS complete_date
    FROM completed_training
    GROUP BY complete_training_id
) completed ON completed.user_id = s.user_id
AND completed.area_id = s.area_id
AND completed.course_id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
LEFT JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = s.area_id
LEFT JOIN training_courses tc ON tc.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE u.active = 1
AND o.active = 1
AND s.assigned = 1
```

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why you have not group your inner query with user_id ,area_id ,course_id?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: In the inner query put all the columns in group by clause.

Comment: Yeah that didnt make any difference, there are still duplicate columns

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?  You can do this with Ranking function.  They are new on mysql 8, but a trick can be used for older version.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Mysql 5.6.  I would of thought this query wouldn't be so complicated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly positive of your expected results, but the failure is PROBABLY for your group by and JOIN.  Your group by is ONLY on the training ID, but you are also pulling user, area and course as well as max date completed for said respective training ID, user, area, course.  You group by and join should match the unique characteristics.

Without seeing data, the query as I interpret it is that the "complete_training_id" is an auto-increment column for that table.  Having said that, there would only ever be one record for that ID.

Having said that, the completed training table can have for a single user, area and course, multiple training days of which you want the most recent.  For example someone attending college and needs to take many computer classes and they are refreshers from prior so assume all are same course ID.  A person could take in 2012, 2014, 2016.  You would want the instance of the user/area/course showing the 2016 dated training. So lets look at that first.

```
select
      ct.user_id,
      ct.area_id,
      ct.course_id,
      max(ct.completed_on) AS complete_date
   FROM 
      completed_training ct
   GROUP BY 
      ct.user_id,
      ct.area_id,
      ct.course_id
```

Now, for each user, area and course of study, I have one record with the most recent completion date.  NOW lets pull the rest of the details, but since you need the completed training ID too, I applied the MAX() of that in the query below.  The ID should by default be increasing every time a new record is added, so one completed a year ago would have a lower value than the ID completed today.  So you get both the completed ID and its corresponding date for a given user, area, course.

```
SELECT
      s.course_stat_id,
      o.org_name,
      u.id,
      u.first_name,
      u.last_name,
      a.area_id,
      a.area_name,
      tc.course_id,
      tc.course_name,
      s.assigned_on,
      s.due,
      s.pass_mark,
      s.completed_on,
      ct.complete_training_id,
      ct.complete_date
   FROM 
      training_stats s
         JOIN organisations o 
            ON s.org_id = o.org_id 
           AND o.active = 1
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( select
                    ct.user_id,
                    ct.area_id,
                    ct.course_id,
                    max(ct.complete_training_id ) as complete_training_id,
                    max(ct.completed_on) AS complete_date
                 FROM 
                    completed_training ct
                 GROUP BY 
                    ct.user_id,
                    ct.area_id,
                    ct.course_id ) ct
            on s.user_id = ct.user_id
            AND s.area_id = ct.area_id
            AND s.course_id = ct.course_id
         JOIN users u 
            ON s.user_id = u.id
            AND u.active = 1
         LEFT JOIN areas a 
            ON s.area_id = a.area_id
         LEFT JOIN training_courses tc 
            ON s.course_id = tc.course_id
   WHERE
      s.assigned = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of that.  First, run this query.  It should list all completed training, with a rnk from 1 (lastest), to n (oldest).

```
    SELECT complete_training_id
          ,user_id
          ,area_id
          ,course_id
          ,completed_on AS complete_date
          ,@curRank := case when complete_training_id <> @cur_complete_training_id then 0 else @curRank + 1 end rnk
    FROM completed_training, (select @curRank := 0, @cur_complete_training_id := 0)
    ORDER BY complete_training_id, completed_on DESC
```

If true, the answer is :

```
SELECT s.course_stat_id
      ,o.org_name
      ,u.id
      ,u.first_name
      ,u.last_name
      ,a.area_id
      ,a.area_name
      ,tc.course_id
      ,tc.course_name
      ,s.assigned_on
      ,s.due
      ,s.pass_mark
      ,s.completed_on
      ,completed.complete_training_id
      ,completed.complete_date
FROM training_stats s
JOIN organisations o ON o.org_id = s.org_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT complete_training_id
          ,user_id
          ,area_id
          ,course_id
          ,completed_on AS complete_date
          ,@curRank := case when complete_training_id <> @cur_complete_training_id then 0 else @curRank + 1 end rnk
    FROM completed_training, (select @curRank := 0, @cur_complete_training_id := 0)
    ORDER BY complete_training_id, completed_on DESC
) completed ON completed.user_id = s.user_id and completed.rnk = 1
AND completed.area_id = s.area_id
AND completed.course_id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
LEFT JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = s.area_id
LEFT JOIN training_courses tc ON tc.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE u.active = 1
AND o.active = 1
AND s.assigned = 1
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I'm getting this error when I try and run that query: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: add an alias after `(select @curRank := 0, @cur_complete_training_id := 0)`